# How to extrapolate the text content within an iframe utilizing DOM and XPath?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, iframe, domxpath

I would like to use `DOMXPath` to extrapolate the text of a message within an `iframe` object.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
$dom->recover = true;

$isSuccessful = @$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://t.me/Chelsea/874');

// Delay 1 second after the request to avoid getting BANNED
sleep(1);

// Check to see if URL is valid
if($isSuccessful === false)
{
    //URL invalid!
    echo "\"".$url."\" is invalid<br>";
    return false;
}

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs=$xpath->query('//*[@id="widget"]/iframe');
```

However, the length of the array is `0`.

How can I extrapolate the text content within the class `tgme_widget_message_text` of the `iframe`?

Comment: Is it only me? I don't see an `iframe` or an element with class `tgme_widget_message_text` on that page

Comment: @kerbholz please check the link with a browser that supports iframes, the element with the class `tgme_widget_message_text` is inside the `iframe`. Check it here: https://ibb.co/nwc3i0

Comment: Oh I see. The `iframe` does not appear in the source code, it's added via Javascript. That might be your problem.

Comment: @kerbholz any possible workaround?